# I have a lot of traffic and only 1 server best config for nginx/varnish/apache configuration

Tags: redirect, php-fpm, varnish, 301-redirect, memcached

I have a lot of traffic and only 1 server can I get some help with configuration

**Nginx.conf config:**

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
    listen *:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
            server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sitename.com/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sitename.com/privkey.pem;
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
            }
    }

}
```

**default.vcl config:**

```
#
# This is an example VCL file for Varnish.
#
# It does not do anything by default, delegating control to the
# builtin VCL. The builtin VCL is called when there is no explicit
# return statement.
#
# See the VCL chapters in the Users Guide at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/
# and https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples for more examples.

# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

#acl upstream_proxy {
#  "127.0.0.1";
#}

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  # Set the X-Forwarded-For header so the backend can see the original
  # IP address. If one is already set by an upstream proxy, we'll just re-use that.

  #return(pass);

  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
     return (purge);
  }

  if (req.method == "XCGFULLBAN") {
     ban("req.http.host ~ .*");
     return (synth(200, "Full cache cleared"));
  }

  if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
     return(pass);
  }

  if (req.http.Authorization || req.method == "POST") {
     return (pass);
  }

  if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
     return (pass);
  }

  if (req.url ~ "(wp-admin|post\.php|edit\.php|wp-login|wp-json)") {
     return(pass);
  }

  if (req.url ~ "/wp-cron.php" || req.url ~ "preview=true") {
     return (pass);
  }
  if (req.url ~ "/xmlrpc.php" || req.url ~ "preview=true") {
     return (pass);
  }

  if ((req.http.host ~ "woowonder.com" && req.url ~ "^some_specific_filename\.(css|js)")) {
     return (pass);
  }

# Unset Cookies except for WordPress admin and WooCommerce pages
if (!(req.url ~ "(cart|my-account/*|wc-api*|checkout|addons|logout|lost-password|ask-question|product/*)")) {
unset req.http.cookie;
}
# Pass through the WooCommerce dynamic pages
if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account/*|checkout|wc-api/*|addons|logout|lost-password|ask-question|product/*)") {
return (pass);
}
# Pass through the WooCommerce add to cart
if (req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
return (pass);
}
# Pass through the WooCommerce API
if (req.url ~ "\?wc-api=" ) {
return (pass);


  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");

  # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove the wp test cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove the PHPSESSID in members area cookie
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "PHPSESSID=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  unset req.http.Cookie;
}

sub vcl_purge {
    set req.method = "GET";
    set req.http.X-Purger = "Purged";

    #return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    return (restart);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.

    set beresp.grace = 12h;
    set beresp.ttl = 12h;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
}

sub vcl_hash {
  if(req.http.X-UA-Device ~ "(mobile|tablet)") {
    hash_data("mobile");
  }
}
```

**httpd.conf config:**

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User apache
Group apache

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin root@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName onooks.com

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts.
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
# interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the
# default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
# in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
# directive:
#
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it,
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults if commented: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

**redirect information:**

```
    >>> http://sitename.com

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Fri, 13 Mar 2020 22:14:09 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=pet551pq0piaomea16i2614fvd; path=/
X-Powered-By:   PHP/7.4.2
Expires:    Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Redirect-By:  WordPress
Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Frame-Options:    DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location:   https://sitename.com/
X-Varnish:  830862
Age:    0
Via:    1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
CF-Cache-Status:    DYNAMIC
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 57391b33fed76b4d-LHR
alt-svc:    h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-25=":443"; ma=86400, h3-24=":443"; ma=86400, h3-23=":443"; ma=86400




>>> https://sitename.com/

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Fri, 13 Mar 2020 22:14:10 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=72tm47a87kbd1ridfg37q6kahi; path=/
X-Powered-By:   PHP/7.4.2
Expires:    Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Redirect-By:  WordPress
Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Frame-Options:    DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location:   https://www.sitename.com/
X-Varnish:  830865
Age:    0
Via:    1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
CF-Cache-Status:    DYNAMIC
Expect-CT:  max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 57391b36abb8dc4f-LHR
alt-svc:    h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-25=":443"; ma=86400, h3-24=":443"; ma=86400, h3-23=":443"; ma=86400




>>> https://www.sitename.com/

> --------------------------------------------
> 200 OK
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 200 OK
Code:   200
Date:   Fri, 13 Mar 2020 22:14:11 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=n0cf0f29lh06hib0lrnij4mdv6; path=/
X-Powered-By:   PHP/7.4.2
Expires:    Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Link:   <https://www.sitename.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://www.sitename.com/>; rel=shortlink
Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Frame-Options:    DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Varnish:  374644
Age:    0
Via:    1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
CF-Cache-Status:    DYNAMIC
Expect-CT:  max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 57391b399efee660-LHR
alt-svc:    h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-25=":443"; ma=86400, h3-24=":443"; ma=86400, h3-23=":443"; ma=86400
```

Using:
php-fpm 7.4
apache 2.4
mariadb 10.5

On top of this i have the nameservers at cloudflare.

The website is a cms so cpu problem.

**I have 32gb and 32 threads what is the best way to config my server for the best results ?**

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you create a cache variation for HTTPS traffic. You can do this as follows:

```
sub vcl_hash {
  if(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
  }
}
```

But since you already have a cache variation for the mobile website, I suggest you combine it as follows:

```
sub vcl_hash {
  if(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
  }
  if(req.http.X-UA-Device ~ "(mobile|tablet)") {
    hash_data("mobile");
  }
}
```

Comment: still showing the desktop version instead of the mobile version. I really appreciate your help btw.

Comment: any other idea Thijs Feryn to fix the mobile reposniness for example because of varnish ?